# Computer Architecture : Out of order execution - Load/Store

Tags: architecture, computer-architecture

In Out of Order execution , what happens if there is a **younger store that executes before an older load**. Wont the load get the wrong data provided the younger store writes to the same address? 
I understand the memory disambiguation problem i.e **when younger load depends on older store** which is the flip side to my question.

Example :-
Older   A : Load R1 <- R0(8)
Younger B : Store R2 -> R3(25)

The case is , if B executes before A with R3(25)=R0(8) [i.e store writes to the address and later load instr gets the new data if its allowed to execute which is wrong!!]. How is this case handled ??

Answer (score 1):

Out of order execution is a microarchitecture detail. The CPU may reorder instructions only when this doesn't change the observable or specified behaviour. Here, this can be achieved in one of two ways:

- When the CPU issues a speculative memory access but that speculation was wrong, the CPU must roll back the effects of speculative execution.
- When there are multiple accesses to the same memory location, they must be resolved according to the architecture's memory model. This could mean that stores and loads to the same address are only executed in their proper order. Out of order execution of such accesses wouldn't be possible.

In your example, you seem to assume that accessing the same memory location via different registers and different offsets will confuse the CPU. This is not the case. The CPU can only execute instructions out of order if it can detect such conflicts (if this access would be a conflict according to its memory model). A simple algorithm to avoid this kind of conflict would be to not execute any writes while loads are still in progress.

Comment: "In your example, you seem to assume that accessing the same memory location via different registers and different offsets will confuse the CPU. This is not the case." – One could argue that that is more or less what SPECTRE and friends are, although it is a very specific and very subtle kind of "confusion" and not at all like the OP thinks. (I guess technically it is more the CPU *designers* getting confused.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Hmm, even with Spectre the CPU does properly roll back the results of memory accesses so that programs continue to execute correctly even with wrong speculation. The issue is that internal caches and predictions are not rolled back, and that this is observable through timings. Spectre is not a correctness bug but the result of an unsuitable security model.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of Load Store Queue (LSQ) in Computer Architecture. You always keep the instructions in the order in LSQ.

| L/S | Address | Value | Commit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L | ? | ? | No |
| S | 0x11 | 6 | No |

The above table is a representation of LSQ. The first row corresponds to Older A(Load) and the second row corresponds to Younger B.(Store)
If the Store is computed first, the value will be in the LSQ. It won't be immediately written to the cache. The store will be written to the cache or memory only after the second row is committed. And the commit always happens in order. So, when the first row computes the address, it will get the value from cache or memory, which would be the old value. After the first row commits, the second row will also commit, and then only you would see the updated value in cache or memory.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU will *always* behave as if all instructions were executed in program order. If the CPU can’t reorder instructions and guarantee correctness at the same time, it won’t reorder.

If both addresses for load and store are known, the CPU can check that there is no conflict and do a store to location y before a load from location x, if the locations are known to be different.

If the address of the load is unknown, then any following store has to wait. Same if the addresses are the same, or cannot be guaranteed to be different (on many architectures, the same data can be accessed using different addresses that are multiple pages apart).

How much effort is put into the design and hardware will depend on the amount of benefits. And a CPU might remember that you stored to locate even if you couldn’t perform the store yet, a later load from that address will then just take the value that ought to be stored.

PS. Some processors even do something very similar to branch prediction: If there is a store to location X, followed by a load from location Y, the processor may *predict* either that X and Y are different, or that they are the same. In the first case, a load from Y is performed even when we can’t guarantee to get the right result. In the second case, we use the value stored to X as the result of the load.

At some point in the future the processor will detect whether X and Y are the same or not, and then either processing continues, or all results since the incorrect prediction are removed.